# When writing VB forms app, what is programatic equivalent of selecting Properties > Compatibility > "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"?

Tags: vb.net, dpi

When writing VB forms app in MSVS2010, what is programmatic equivalent of locating the application's EXE, right clicking and selecting Properties > Compatibility > "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings"?

In Visual Studio: tried:

- Using Manifest file and setting application to dpiaware

  ```
  <dpiAware> true </dpiAware>
  ```

(maybe I didn't edit the manifest correctly by not putting this is in the correct location). [The only example I had access to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062612/how-to-activate-disable-display-scaling-on-high-dpi-settings-programatically) was on a CSharp project and perhaps it works differently in VB.

- Design Editor Properties on the main form: AutoSize: False, AutoScaleMode: None, Font, DPI, Inherit - all of which made no difference whatsoever.

Comment: If you check the app.manifest file before and after you make that change, do you see any difference in the app.manifest code?  You may want to restart VS after making the change but BEFORE checking for a difference in the app.manifest code.

Comment: No, there was no differences but I'm also not sure where to put it either, so it may have been that the location I chose to modify the manifest file was wrong. I tried googling some references about the manifest file so that I may understand it's structure a little better but I was unable to find anything.